# Misplaced \noalign error when trying to knit a pdf using RMarkdown/kable

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit a pdf where I print a list of dataframes to a pdf. I have the following code which gives me the following error:

```
---
geometry: margin=1.7cm
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 3.5
    fig_width: 6.4
    keep_tex: yes
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_file=paste0('IIDP Data Dictionary ',Sys.Date(),'.pdf')) })
---
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.align='center', message=FALSE)
source("H:/IU_DataManagement/Data_Dict_Code_IIDP_20201104.R")
\newpage
\begin{center}
\section{Demographic Variables}
\end{center}
{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
## tables
for(i in seq_along(demo)) {
  print(
      kable(demo[[i]], format = "latex", caption = names(demo)[i], longtable = TRUE, col.names = NULL) %>%
          kable_styling(font_size = 7, latex_options = "repeat_header", full_width = FALSE)
  )
}
### There are 19 other for loops that use the same format but a different list.
```

The error I recieve and do not know what it means is:

! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign
{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \hskip \vskip \let \vrule \hrule \let...
l.15724 348}\textbackslash{} \hline
453 & Variable Name &

Error: LaTeX failed to compile IIDP Data Dictionary 2020-11-05.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See IIDP Data Dictionary 2020-11-05.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You should be able to find the tex file here. Im happy to distribute it another way as well. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/luuzptywj2d7tv5/AAC23U5xWNzVL7mEPjPf5jPHa?dl=0

Comment: While most of your tables produce proper tex code,  pandoc seems to incorrectly escape a couple of them and produce gibberish like `\textbackslash begin` Can you you boil your markdown file down to a small example that includes one working table, one broken table and the necessary data to run the example?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am able to print one of my for loops just fine but for some reason the row numbers are printing out as well.  I each list comes from a large dataframe read in by a CSV that I subsetted by 20 different variable types. Im confused how to not print the row numbers.

I will continue to play around with adding each variable one by one to see which is the culprit.